# Getting proper dataframe output in integrated PyCharm jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am having an issue with displaying dataframe properly in Jupyter Notebook that is integrated into PyCharm.

Here is what I am seeing:

[image: running print(df) command]

This happens where I run `print(df)`.  I know that in Jupyter Notebook you can simply write `df` and it should output the dataframe..

[image: running df command]

Ideally, I'd even like for the dataframe to ouput as a table, as I have seen this before in Jupyter.. How can I configure this?

Comment: What if you do `from IPython.display import display; display(df)`?

Comment: Getting `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Check my updated comment please?

Comment: Seems as though it is working.. Here is the issue - I think that the table is not showing properly in PyCharm itself... like do you notice where i have simply `df` -- there is a little line trying to show a table, but it is not displaying it... maybe a different issue